# Real 1 not equal to complex 1

Tags: paradoxes

We have the set-theoretic definition for pairs as:
(x , y) = {{x}, {x, y}}
Also we have the definition:
complex 1 = (1, 0)
So if real 1 = complex 1 we would have:
1 = (1, 0) = {{1}, {1, 0}}
Which seems paradoxical. Am I missing a point?

Comment: In the complex "space" the real $1$ is the complex $(1,0)$.

Comment: Nice question, +1. Ultimately I think the point you are 'missing' is that in reality no-one thinks about numbers (or other mathematical objects) in terms of their set-theoretic definitions. But of course this is not an answer to your question in the strict sense.

Comment: If we think in terms of sets, we have that the set of complex numbers has a subset that "looks like" the set of real, that is not exactly the same as considering the reals a subset of the complex.

Comment: Real $1$ is *identified* with complex $1$ but not identical

Comment: Yes, technically each formal theory (real line, complex plane, set theory) has its own realization of $1$, but this is glossed over when one theory is embedded into another. Without the gloss we get what is called ["junk theorems"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90820/set-theories-without-junk-theorems), like $1\in2$ in set theory.

Comment: Real $1$ and complex $1+0i$ are elements of different fields so you cannot really compare them.

Comment: This is not an *exact* duplicate, but the answers are the same. This is about setting up context for inclusion, and whether or not $\Bbb{R\subseteq C}$ or $\Bbb{N\nsubseteq Q}$ is a matter of convention. In either case we do have *canonical* embeddings, so we *may* identify the canonical copy inside each "larger" structure. Whether or not we choose to do so is up to what is more convenient.